# Field lookup to activity section

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to create a field that will show me the days since I last talked to a contact on the phone. I want it to show up in my contacts information, but pull the data from activities. The call can either be result: LVM or Conversation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Hal, what exactly is your question here - "any thoughts?" is quite broad. Do you perhaps want to know if it's possible to update this field automatically, or do you have an implementation but need help fixing a bug?

Comment: I'd like to have a field that will show me exactly how many days it has been since I talked to someone on the phone (a contact). I know there is a standard field "Days since last activity" but I want to have the field updated as a result of a subset of an activity: i.e. I log a call as a conversation (an activity field) it would reset to 0, but if I log a call as LVM, it would continue to count (move from 4 days to 5 days and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach,

1) Write a trigger on Activity, to update the latest activity date to related contact.
 2) Create a formula field on contact to calculate the number of days between the date updated by trigger and Today().

Comment: I've got to ask, how do I write a trigger? Haha

Comment: Go to Setup -> Customize -> Activity -> Task Trigger/ Event Trigger. Check some documentation - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm